# Another rman issue

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

error I get when I try to run this simple script

```
RMAN> CMDFILE c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\xe\scripts\rman1.rcv

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "cmdfile": expecting one of: "allocate, alter, backup, beginline, blockrecover, catalog, change, connect, copy, convert, create, crosscheck,  configure, duplicate, debug, delete, drop, exit, endinline, flashback, host, {, library,  list, mount, open, print, quit, recover, register, release, replace, report, r
enormalize, reset, restore, resync, rman, run, rpctest, set, setlimit, sql, switch,  spool, startup, shutdown, send, show, test, transport, upgrade, unregister, validate"
RMAN-01007: at line 1 column 1 file: standard input
```

The script is a simple one

```
connect target /;
backup database plus archivelog delete input;
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing was a stupid mistake on my part

C:\Users\Randy>rman cmdfile 'c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\xe\scripts\rman1.rcv' log c:\temp\rman1.rcv.log

I was trying to run this from rman when it should of been ran from a dos/cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RMAN> @c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\xe\scripts\rman1.rcv
```

[Documented here.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14193/toc.htm#i773595)